# Is is possible to attach EntityProxy to another RequestContext ? And should I?

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I have a little form that edits my entity. I create that entity using one instance of RequestContext and then in handler of "save" button I'm trying to persist it using another instance of RequestContext.

Attempt to persist fails with expected exception: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempting to edit an EntityProxy previously edited by another RequestContext`

The questions are:

- Is is possible to attach EntityProxy to another RequestContext ?
- Is it right thing to do ? Or I should reuse one RequestContext saving it
  as property of my class ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reuse the existing one. If you need a new one, merge them. But it really doesn't make sense to make a new one. Here's why:

When you make a RF call to the server, it goes through several steps, as it is geared mostly toward how to read and persist entities, and the various value properties they work with.

- Create or retrieve any of the instances to be dealt with
- Apply setters to these instances, new or existing, and validate them
- Run the service invocations, either as methods invoked on the entities, static calls, or service calls.

These three steps are done in this order to ensure that the object modified and then passed to a service call makes sense when it gets there. Future calls (i.e. other requests) then probably do not need to make those same changes to the same entities, and if they do, then they need to make the changes themselves.

A given `RequestContext` consists of all of these things then. If you had two requests, and one represented the setters to be called (the edits from the form) and the other the service request, firing one means only calling the setters, but not the service call to save it, while firing the other means only call save without the service call.

After an `EntityProxy` has been marked as being edited by one request context, attempting to use it in another one is almost certainly an error, so the exception you are seeing is thrown. Use the existing one, or use `RequestContext.append` if needed to switch to a new `RequestContext` type to actually run the save operation.

RequestFactory isn't RPC - your objects aren't just Java Beans, but are proxies (either `EntityProxy` or `ValueProxy`) of some server object, and requests are used to manipulate them asynchronously.

Comment: Colin, could you please tell me if I should do something with context after I used it to persist the entity ? It works on first call but all subsequent calls cause `java.lang.IllegalStateException: A request is already in progress` to be thrown.

Comment: A `RequestContext` is a kind of one-shot _builder_. Once you `fire()`d it, it's no longer usable (unless there are constraint violations or the request failed due to a network error).

Comment: The only case where it can be reused is where it failed on the server in such a way that it can be resent - I believe the only case for this is when a validation error occurs, so the setters were called, but the service invocation was not. Those setters should be able to be called again after the user corrects their validation issue, and then the invocation made.